# How to set a custom background image in ConEmu?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, conemu

I'm trying to set a custom background in my ConEmu console and I'm a bit puzzled as to the settings I need.

[The documentation](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Settings) mentions a number of Windows registry entries but it isn't clear to me which ones I should modify and how.

In my understanding, `cbBgImage` should be set to enable the image. However, I cannot find any setting for the image path itself in the documentation.

Upon inspection of the registry entries, I can see the following properties at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ConEmu\.Vanilla`

- `BackGround Image` (type: `REG_SZ`, value: `c:\back.bmp`)
- `BackGround Image show` (type: `REG_BINARY`, value: `00`)

none of which seem to appear in the docs.

I tried placing an image at the path `c:\back.bmp` and setting the other property to `11` and restarting ConEmu but the image did not appear.

I'm using ConEmu 6.1.7601 on a 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise. My current setting for the background colour in ConEmu is black and I have transparency enabled.

What do I need to do to have the image show up?

Comment: ConEmu build is visible in the about or settings dialog, for example. Wondering, why users are trying to find the build/version somewhere else? And type it improperly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background image can be easily set up in the Settings dialog on the Main page. Why do you trying to dig the registry?

[image]

Comment: Apparently, I missed the setting so I opened up the docs, which in turn pointed to the registry. I guess I just expected it to be in the `Appearance` sub-menu or perhaps I didn't spot it among the other options. The amount of configurable settings in ConEmu is so good it's scary. I just fired up the settings on my home computer and I can see the relevant config. I'll see if it's the same in the version I have at work. If it is, I'll happily accept the answer.